# How to retrieve the link to a response from a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to take a direct link to the individual response (link looks like https://docs.google.com/forms/d//edit#response=) and paste it in file google spreadsheet. How can I retrieve that link? I get part of the link up to /edit with Form.getEditUrl() but I can't get the correct id. I checked FormResponse.getId() but that doesn't link me to any response. Here's how to get to that link manually via edit form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA1S3.png)

Many thanks :(

Comment: Can you please explain your question better? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Run from the script editor of the form.

```js
function getUrls() {
  const name = 'Sheet Name'; // name of sheet
  const col = 10; // the column number to fill
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const values = [];
  for (const r of formResponses) {
    values.push([r.getEditResponseUrl()]);
  }
  const id = form.getDestinationId();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  sheet.getRange(2, col, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not effective. The statement "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponses' of null (Line 5, "Code.gs")" Can you help me?

Comment: Oh, I tried out. It's show edit url ressponse. I don't need them. I only want the url response (include true/false question of student's test) (eg: https://prnt.sc/1qc4hyu)

Comment: I think it is currently the only method to get a url to the individual responses of Google Form. You may need to develop a web app/use modal to show the read-only responses.

Comment: Alternatively, you can generate prefilled links for the responses acting as dummies